# Find nearest time out of five

Tags: objective-c, date, time, nsdate

I currently have an array with different times. These are user defined and in 30 minute intervals. So, an example could be:

```
NSMutableArray *times = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"9:30", @"12:00", @"13:30", @"17:00", nil];
```

Also, the number of different times can be vary from one to five.

Now I want to find the one that's the closest to the *current* time. So for instance, if it was 11:00 right now, out of the above examples, it would return 12:00.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Parse the string into minutes and hours, convert each into some sort of number format, figure the difference for each one, and return the one with the smallest difference.

Comment: Convert everything to minutes to find the differences easier

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the array of times, comparing each one to the current time. Store the closest one in a variable outside the loop, checking each time against that variable and updating its value only if the iterator value is closer. I'm not posting code on purpose, because this is the kind of thing you need to learn to figure out to be a developer.

Answer (score 0):

Storing String cannot help you on comparing "time". 
Try storing the "times" in [NSTimeInterval](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSTimeInterval).

Then you should be able to compare and select the most nearest time to current time.

EDIT:
The way on how to convert to NSTimeInterval and how to compare should leave back to you to implement.